# Spring MVC: globally injecting properties from persistent layer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a service bean capable of getting / setting property values from persistent layer (eg: database). Something like this:

```
@Service
public ConfigService {
  public String getConfig(String key);
}
```

The problem is for each controller class I write I have to autowire and populate my model with the property key/values:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public FooController {
  @Autowired private ConfigService configService;

  @RequestMapping("/login")
  public String login(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("site.name", configService.getConfig("site.name"));
    //...
  }
}
```

Is there any way I can automatically get the value of this property on my spring JSP view? I don't want to have to inject this to my model object for each controller class I write.

The closest I can get so far is using Spring ResourceBundleMessageSource bean and `<spring:message>` tags, however I am constrained to using properties file, can't store it in database.

Comment: I'm not certain about the Spring JSP taglib, but I know that Thymeleaf templates can retrieve any Spring bean by name (e.g., `configService.config['site.name']`.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way of doing this. Use a `@ControllerAdvice` class combined with `@ModelAttribute` method. Something like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ConfigAdvice {
  @Autowired private ConfigService configService;

  @ModelAttribute
  public void populateConfig(Model model) {
    for(Config config : configService.getAll()) {
      model.addAttribute(config.getKey(), config.getValue());
    }
  }
}
```

The `@ModelAttribute` annotated `populateConfig()` method above will run prior to any `@RequestMapping` method on all other controller classes.

One drawback is config key can't contain any dot characters.

So far this looks to be my best option. Please let me know if there's a better way.